positioning <dialogs> to the right not center
I have a dialog and I want it to be on the right side like a sidebar, but other parts of the page should not be accessible. So I am using a dialog but it's centered and I need it to be on the right hand side.
<dialog ref={dialog} className="contact-modal w-[50%] h-[100vh] max-w-[400px] fixed right-[-60%] overflow-hidden border-none p-6 transition-transform duration-500 ease-in-out">
    <ModalHeader text="Contact ATM Creativity" handleClose={handleClose} />
</dialog>

